# Google Charts API - check for success in drawing

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to draw Column and Line charts. How can I check whether the chart was successfully drawn or not (or, whether the data table was populated with success)?

At the moment I'm only checking whether drawing form has been submitted and make sure that default values are set for array indexes, to avoid any dimensional problems. But I still want to know how to programmatically check for its success or failure.

The only hint I get from Google is this [GadgetHelper Response](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#GadgetHelper) but I'm not using queries to generate the data.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);';
    }
?>

<script>
function drawChart() {
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        <?php
            // populate array via PHP
        ?>
    ]);
    options = {
       // some options
    };
    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options); // some way of checking return value for success??

    // I 'd like to enable this only upon success, not when function is called
    document.getElementById('chart_selector').disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a "ready" event handler for the chart to enable your element when the chart is finished drawing.  You can hook the "error" event as well, if you need to do something if the chart fails to draw.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // do stuff when the chart is done drawing
    document.getElementById('chart_selector').disabled = false;
});
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function () {
    // do stuff when the chart fails to draw
});
chart.draw(data, options);
```

If you need to handle the case where the DataTable constructor fails, you can wrap the constructor call in a try-catch block:

```
try {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    // ...
}
catch (e) {
    alert('DataTable construction failed');
}
```

Comment: cheers :) Although, it would be cool if there was a way of checking BEFORE the chart was drawn. say the data given is invalid, so instead of drawing and getting error, it would just not attempt to draw. But oh well, it's client side and no damage at all ;)

Comment: In what sense do you mean invalid?  Are you talking about failing to create a proper DataTable or data that is in the wrong format for the chart?

Comment: I mean failing to create a proper DataTable.

Comment: If the DataTable fails it should throw an error, so you can wrap your DataTable constructor in a try-catch block, see edit to my answer.